# Show “lock screen” type UI on button press

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I know how to display the keypad when a textfield is selected.  I would like to have the keypad pop up on a button press and some boxes like the lock screen.  Any suggestions on how to execute this?

Comment: Basically I want the textfield entry to be hidden and initiated upon a button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the keypad for a textfield ; [theTextField becomeFirstResponder];